# how to compare hive and mysql performance

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, benchmarking, bigdata

I implemented the same datawarehouse star schema in hive and mysql.  I would dimostrate that Hive is better in terms of query response time.

But I tried with some thousands of records and mysql seems better than hive.  I think Hive is Better with millions of record (in order of gigabyte)

The problem is that I havent a million of records and I havent a clustering of hardware for hadoop.

How I can do it?

If I suppose to have a cluster of 10 servers I could divide the time of query execution in hive by 10?
thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for just millions of record, I think MySQL is better.

Do you really need Hive? How will you use the data? Hive is not suit to real-time analysis. It's for offline analysis. Basically, one SQL query will run at least dozens of seconds in Hive. But for just millions of record, query run in MySQL can return less than 1 second, if your schema is well designed and the indexes are created correctly.

In addition, "If I suppose to have a cluster of 10 servers I could divide the time of query execution in hive by 10", this is wrong. Different queried may have different speed-up ratio. It also depends on the data distribution. In extreme case, Hive may only use one machine to run the query, e.g., cross join.

Comment: I haven't a real use case. I wrote a thesis with a simple data warehouse that aggregates data from social networks and search engines. So in theory I have billions of record. I want to dimostrate with benchmarks that Hive is better than mySql for big data warehousing.

Comment: What's your use case, real-time or offline? Which one is better depends on your use case. There is no Silver Bullet

Comment: Offline analysis... write once read many. does exist online testing platform that offers data and clustering for Experimental use?